# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _isSumLess referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, mixed

I keep getting the `: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _isSumLess referenced in function _main`

I cant seem to link these two together and I don't see whats going on, Ive tried using the #undef main as said in other threads but nothing is working.
here is my code.

It is linked with some assembly code. 
The fist portion works fine however it seems to not know what isSumLess is, if 
I replace that with the first largestOfFour it will run that again as well so it looks fine to me but I'm probably over looking something,

Thanks.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#undef main

extern "C" {
    int32_t largestOfFour(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t d);
}
extern "C" {
    int32_t isSumLess(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t z );
}

int main()
{
    int32_t a, b, c, d;
    printf("CSIS-165 PA7\n\n");

    printf("Enter 4 integers, separated by comma: ");
    scanf_s("%d, %d, %d, %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("Values read [%d] [%d] [%d] [%d] \n", a, b, c, d);

    printf("The Largest of the first two is ");

    largestOfFour(a, b, c, d);


    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");

    int32_t x, y, z;
    //PART 2

    printf("Part 2\n ");
    printf("Enter 3 integers, separated by comma: ");
    scanf_s("%d, %d, %d", &x, &y, &z);
    printf("Values read [%d] [%d] [%d]\n", x, y, z);
    printf("result ");

    isSumLess(x,y,z);

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reason: the compiler is unable to find the definition of isSumLess

Comment: Thanks! got it, It was a problem in my .asm, I bottle necked it on accident so it would end before getting them.